# Rails Testing : Array to be loaded in fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

I have an array of data whose presence I need to check in method, and now I have to write a test cases for that using MiniTest. Now issue is how to load the array in fixture because fixture only contains hashes or array inside hashes.

e.g

```
HUMAN_SPECIES = [INDIAN, AMERICAN, AFRICAN, RUSSIAN]

def allow_human
  HUMAN_SPECIES.include?(human_species)
    # Statement
end.
```

Need to write HUMAN_SPECIES in fixture.yml. How ?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

This must work:

```
model_name_test:
  human_species:
    - INDIAN
    - AFRICAN
```

Comment: And why exactly is that?

Comment: this will actually work, a list with '-' is how yaml describes an array.